# Data not loading in UITableView after parsing in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, activity-indicator

I'm trying to implement an activity indicator when I parse my XML data.

I found this [Activity indicator (spinner) with UIActivityIndicatorView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262738/activity-indicator-spinner-with-uiactivityindicatorview) and have it working. However, because I'm using `performSelectorInBackground` when it finishes parsing none of the data shows up in my tableview.

I have tried [self.tableview reloadData] and I've tried [self.view setNeedsDisplay] however, nothing seems to work.

If I leave the view and come back to it, all the data appears in the tableview cells.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you adding the data to the table view? Can you show all related code?

Comment: you should look at `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Comment: @KerrM All my parsing and retrieving the RSS Feed occur in a file that I import into my view controller. 

In my view controller, I do this: `self.rssNews = [[ParseRSSNews alloc] initWithUrl:self.url];`
In initWithUrl method in the parser file, I did this: 
`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseXMLFileAtURL:) withObject:url];`
Once it is done parsing, I did: 
`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneParsing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

when I print out how many items are in my self.rssNews (in view controller), that it shows 0. So, it's not returning the data.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to call reloadData on the *main thread*.

Comment: @cdstamper Thank you! I figured it out =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
[self.tableview reloadData]
```

in the **main** **thread** (you can check in wich thread you'r in with [NSThread isMainThread])

you can do

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
//create background queue
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
//dispatch in background
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        //execute long operation in background thread
        self.rssNews = [[ParseRSSNews alloc] initWithUrl:self.url];
    //dispatch in main thread after long operation is finish
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  [self.tableView reloadData]; });
});
```

Comment: Since my parsing and retrieving the RSS feed occur in a separate file, I don't have access to self.tableview.

I was able to do this in my view controller:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.rssNews = [[ParseRSSNews alloc] initWithUrl:self.url];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });`

However, the network indicator doesn't go while it's parsing.

Comment: Thank you Boris!! This helped a LOT!!! I also added to turn off the networkActivityIndicatorVisible within the second dispatch_async(). 

Again, Appreciate all of your help!!! =)

Comment: I'm guessing I would need to release the dispatch queue? I tried doing this in dealloc, `dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);` but Xcode says ARC forbids explicit message send of release -- so I guess ARC will handle releasing the dispatch queue and I shouldn't have to do anything for that?

Comment: Found the answer: 

`If your deployment target is iOS 6.0 or Mac OS X 10.8 or later ARC will manage your queue for you. You do not need to (and cannot) use dispatch_retain or dispatch_release if ARC is enabled.`

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues